# Kill all child processes before closing main Application (Selenium & WebDriver Processes)

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mono

I'm working with Selenium in my .NET Application, when using quit() on either a Firefox or Chrome driver the browser processes do not close correctly however the WebDriver process gets closed. So when my Application terminates the remaining Firefox and Chrome processes remain opened in the background (as child processes to my Application).

[Screenshot when running normally with Firefox Driver Running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0ACP.png)

[After trying to using quit() and closing my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sf6mD.png)

I'm looking for a way to close the WebDriver and the browser processes with it (without using a lazy "kill all processes named 'chrome' or 'firefox'"), if this is not possible then a a way to terminate all child processes associated with my Application when it exits would work for me too.

The current solutions that are available makes use of ManagementObjectSearcher but this would not be ideal because it would not work with Linux (Mono) but only on Windows.

- I've tried to close all Windows using close() before using quit() but the browser process still remains opened
- I've tried to debug the statements to see if it's actually sending a quit command to the Web Driver and it is.

Since i am using a RemoteDriver that is connected to a DriverService, i am using quit() on the RemoteDriver before disposing of the DriverService.

I expect all browser processes including WebDrivers to be closed when i use quit() or at least have a solution to terminate all child processes associated with my application to be killed before exiting the Application. But only the web drivers get closed and the browser processes remain opened in the background.

Chrome when not in headless mode, does actually close the Window but the process remains opened.

Firefox when not in headless mode, does not close the Window at all. even when using close()

Example Code

```cs
// Creating the RemoteDriver with Options
var DriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
var DriverOptions = new ChromeOptions();
DriverOptions.AddArgument("headless");
DriverOptions.AddArgument("mute-audio");
DriverService.Start();
var RemoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(DriverService.ServiceUrl, DriverOptions);

// Quitting
RemoteDriver.Quit();
DriverService.Dispose();
```

---

**Update**

After testing the same code on Linux, the browser processes has closed as expected unlike the problem that i faced when using Windows 10. After some more searching i discovered that other people has faced the same issue, [see this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/6317) and it seems to either be a problem related to a Windows update or the WebDrivers (I'm using the latest drivers that are available and stable) However this issue has not been opened or mentioned in a while.

In conclusion, this problem is only on Windows and more specifically Windows 10. There is still no solution to this problem and it's out of the reach of Selenium and more towards a WebDriver issue. Still.

---

**Update**

[This is an issue](https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/44) on Opera as well, a desirable workaround as i mentioned above would be to kill all child processes associated with your process. **To those who keep saying "USE CLOSE BEFORE QUIT" is not a solution as i explained more than once what i have already tried and what the unexpected results were**

The solution i mentioned above can be accomplished with "ManagementObjectSearcher" but since i made this post i have learnt that this issue is only reproducible on Windows and is out of reach from your code, Selenium and more to do with the WebDriver or Browsers themselves. So the solution is to only use ManagementObjectSearcher to kill child processes associated with your process if you are running on Windows, because this will not work on Mono. But you don't need to worry since i already explained that this issue is not reproducible on Linux, only Windows.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.  It won't help in cases where the driver has crashed (it's Java):

```
 boolean closecaught = false;

 try
 {
   if (driver!=null) {  driver.close(); }
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     closecaught = true;
     System.out.println(e.toString());
     try {
                driver.quit();
            }
            catch (Exception exce)
            {

                System.out.println("Exception quitting" + exce.toString());
            }
 }
 if (closecaught)
 {

 }
 else
 {
     try
 {
   driver.quit();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     // don't worry it should close
 }
```

Comment: I just explained that when using quit() it does not properly close all the browser processes that were started by the WebDriver so when my Application terminates the browser processes remain opened as a child process to my process. See the images i provided above.

Comment: yep...  the different drivers act differently...  at least when I wrote this shutdown code they did.  Close() should close the browser and I think for some drivers it also quits. The multiple processes you are seeing there are kind of deceptive... it's really just one browser launching all those.  If you close the first instance, all the rest will close.  If you find that catching the exceptions doesn't help, there are methods for windows machines for detecting the processes and kill()ing them.

Comment: close() just closes the current window/tab but even when i loop through all windows and close them. the browser process is still active.

Comment: did you run driver.quit() afterwards, or is the driver gone at that point?

Comment: As i already explained, i ran driver.quit() first on the RemoteDriver and disposed of DriverService since there is no method to quit or exit the DriverService. With quit() the WebDriver process has closed but the actual browser processes remained opened.